# Why can one see the outline of a white sheet of paper kept on another white sheet of paper?

Tags: optics

Why can you see the outline of an object of a color that is in front of another object of the same color.

Comment: My guess is that this is because the top paper has finite thickness and therefore creates a shadow in non-perpendicular light.

Comment: @andynitrox Is there a way to shine perfectly perpendicular light and then observe?

Comment: You could probably use sunlight where you let a small section pass through an aperture. The sun's rays are nearly parallel. If you then manage to shine this perpendicular on your paper, the shadow should vanish (nearly).

Comment: But even then  (parallel light) I believe the difference in angular reflectivity on the paper's edge vs. surface will be enough to identify the boundaries of the top sheet.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft What exactly do you mean by 'angular reflectivity' ?

Comment: @milindsrivastava1997  The "bidirectional reflectance distribution function" describes the fraction of light incident at one angle which is reflected at a given angle.  It's a way of comparing real materials' scatter to that of an ideal Lambertian surface.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Is it possible in any case that the angular reflectivity on an object's edge be same as that on its surface or is it theoretically impossible?